# How can I display a specific number of post in a category via a url

Tags: posts, wp-query, categories, urls, variables

I'm trying to link to a specific category in my blog but limit the number of posts that are listed.

I can link to the specific category via "www.example.com/?cat=6" and after looking around the web (wordpress.org and this site) I thought I could just limit the number of posts with "www.example.com/?cat=6&showposts=5" but...

"&showposts=5" isn't returning the results that I'm expecting, am I using "showposts" correctly? Is there something better?

If not how can I build my url to only show a specific number of posts?

While I have access to the theme and the loop, I would prefer not to edit that and not install some plugin, my feed is perfect, I'd just like to build a link for this one type of use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showposts` is an alias of `posts_per_page`, which is a private query var, meaning it can't be set from the query string. You could register your own query var and map that to `posts_per_page` in a `pre_get_posts` action. This could go in your theme's `functions.php` and would work for any main query.

```
// add a new query var to the list of known query vars
function wpd_custom_posts_queryvar( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'wpd-num';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_custom_posts_queryvar' );

// hook pre_get_posts and set posts_per_page
// if it's the main query and our custom query var is set 
function wpd_custom_posts_number( $query ){
    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->get( 'wpd-num' ) ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $query->get( 'wpd-num' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_custom_posts_number' );
```